# How to draw point to a QGraphicsView at run time without clearing the previous drawn points?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am new to Qt, How to draw point to a QGraphicsView at run time without clearing the previous drawn points? I have implemented a simple app which draw points without using timer. I want to update this using timer. How to do this? Please help.

```
     QApplication a(argc, argv);
     QGraphicsScene scene(0,0,640,480);
     QGraphicsView view(&scene);
     QPen pen(Qt::black);
     int x = 0;
     int y = 0;

     double rad = 1;
     while(y < 640)
     {
        scene.addEllipse(x-rad, y-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0, QPen(), QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
        x++;
        y++;
     }

    view.show();
    return a.exec();
```

Comment: u mean with the help of timer u want to draw points...

Comment: i.e after each specific interval u want to draw point

Comment: yes. I need to update the GUI every second without clearing the previous drawn points

Comment: then implement timer for this..

Comment: but in timer function, I cudn't update the GUI. I am stuck in it. Cud u plz help me

Comment: can u provide the code for timer function...'

Comment: QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &scene, SLOT(updateStatus()));
    timer.start();

Comment: What I have to be write inside updateStatus?

Comment: write ur code for drawing points...

Comment: yes it works :) it was due to my aware of CPP calls

Answer (score 1):

Created the scene, view and pen as member variables of MainWindow class and initializes in its constructor.

Call timer function from main.cpp

```
    MainWindow w;

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &w, SLOT(updateStatus()));
    timer.start(0);
```

In MainWindow.cpp created a slot as shown below.

```
void MainWindow::updateStatus()
{
    m_scene->addLine(m_x,m_y,m_x,m_y,*m_pen);
    m_x++;
    m_y++;
}
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code for drawing points in the slot of timer.